# Create a new column is returning as list

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, stringr

I have a dataframe. I need to remove "href" and hence I am using str_match_all. But after removing "href", the class of new column is showing as list. Can anyone help me

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("<a href=https://abc>Click Here</a>","sdsd","<a href=https://xvd>Click Here</a>"))
asd$ew <- str_match_all(asd$a, "http[s]{0,1}://[^ ]+")
asd
                                   a                ew
<a href=https://abc>Click Here</a>        https://abc>Click
                              sdsd                  
<a href=https://xvd>Click Here</a>        https://xvd>Click
class(asd$ew)
"list"
```

Expected output

```
class(asd$ew)
 "character"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as.character`:

```
> asd$ew <- as.character(str_match_all(asd$a, "http[s]{0,1}://[^ ]+"))
> class(asd$ew)
[1] "character"
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `stringr::str_extract` instead of `stringr::str_match_all`.

```
asd$ew <- stringr::str_extract(asd$a, "http[s]{0,1}://[^ ]+")
#asd$ew <- stringr::str_extract(asd$a, "https?://[^ ]+") #Alternative
class(asd$ew)
#[1] "character"

asd
#                                   a                ew
#1 <a href=https://abc>Click Here</a> https://abc>Click
#2                               sdsd              <NA>
#3 <a href=https://xvd>Click Here</a> https://xvd>Click
```